# How to fetch and XML file from Servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, fetch

I'm trying to fetch an XML file from and Java Servlet. I watch a lot of tutorials but none of the ones I've seen work.

In my index.html a wrote the next function

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
                fetch("AppServlet")
                        .then(response => console.log(response));
            });
```

And the response of that fetch is ...

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8080/TW/AppServlet", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:8080/TW/AppServlet"
__proto__: Response
```

But the problem is with my AppServlet. I have no idea how to send one XML file located in my WEB PAGES directory.
Is there an easy way to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your servlet you have to overwrite the doGet() method if you want to respond to get requests.

For sending an xml file I think it would be something like this.

```
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    File xmlFile = new File("someFile.xml"); //Your file location
    long length = xmlFile.length();

    resp.setContentType("application/xml");
    resp.setContentLength((int) length);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlFile))) {
      int bytesRead = 0;
      while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
    }

    out.flush();
  }
```